# Method for using git to keep private repositories in sync

Tags: git

We have a development environment that spans two physical locations.

We are in the very early stages of trying to merge software development efforts that have been, up until now, silo'd. Lots of duplication etc...

One location drives the development while the other is really just coming up to speed. One major issue is that the lead development team is on very archaic servers and doesn't utilize the newer GitHub style coding methodologies; We are looking to adopt Pull Requests and code reviews as they have advantages for how we release to customers.

Here is the set-up.

Location A uses Gitolite and has the "master" repositories

Location B uses GitLab because we want to adopt the use of Pull-Requests and managing users can be done through the web-interface which takes admin burden off of me (we are small). Among other features we like.

What I have attempted to do, which I thought would be simple, is set up a cron job in Location B that simply pulls from Location A and then Pushes to location B in the night (opposite time zones).

Well its proven to be sort of a PITA. I can't seem to find a way to easily fetch all the remote branches having not checked them out in some manual way before. Which results in branches never being pushed to Location B.

Am I missing something obvious? Is this just plain stupid what I am trying to do? The end goal is that we get Location A and B using 1 server running GitLab but that might take a while and some convincing of people.

SSH access is all figured out and working as well as the cron job. It's really that I just can't finagle git into doing what I want. I can do a fetch --all but then it grabs from the Location B remote as well... not what I want.

Here is the start of a script to try to fetch all of the remote branches from one origin but it has all sorts of problems:

```
remote=locationA ; 
for brname in `
  git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD 
  | awk '{gsub(/[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'
`; do 
  git branch --set-upstream-to $brname $brname; 
  # or
  git branch --track $brname  $brname ; 
done
```

I'll continue to work the issue. Just thought I would post here to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious or going down a ridiculous path.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your predicament correctly. When you say your cron job runs in location B, do you mean a machine other than your server? If it is running on the server, just ask the cron job to `git remote update`. I believe that does a fetch and whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I was asking for help with using git-python.

I wrote a script to iterate through the remotes for any given repository. If the remote is 'origin' (Location A) then the script fetches all the branches and tags. Then the script pushes everything to the 'secondary' (Location B) repo.

I can run this script using fcron so I essentially end up with a constantly updated "mirror" of a repository.

Again, not sure if this was just some sort of crazy problem I got myself into or if there is a much simpler way of doing it. But this worked.

Script, for reference, is here but it isn't 100% complete so please use wisely.

"""
gitSync.py

The purpose of this script is to automate a gitSync between two 
repositories. This will pull all branches and tags from one remote
and then push them to another.

```
"""
import git
from git import Repo
import os


def main():

    join = os.path.join
    repo = Repo(os.getcwd())
    git = repo.git
    assert not repo.bare

    for remote in repo.remotes:
        print remote
        if str(remote) == 'origin':
            for ref in remote.refs:
                print " " + str(ref)
                try:
                    git.checkout(str(ref), '-t')
                except:
                    print "Could not check-out branch. It probably already exists"
            git.fetch(str(remote))
            git.fetch('-t', str(remote))
            git.pull
            git.push('secondary', '--all')
            git.push('secondary', '--tags')


#-------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```